# Calculate the average over time, not over group

Tags: python, pandas

I can't get a mean of a value over time.

I have a list of sensor readings at specific times, and I want to get hourly averages of the sensor value.

```py
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    import numpy
    import pandas

    key_id = 1234
    key_label = "Sensor1"
    t_0 = datetime(2010,1,2,12)
    data = [
        [t_0 - timedelta(seconds=120), key_id, 0],
        [t_0 + timedelta(seconds=1800), key_id, 1],
        [t_0 + timedelta(seconds=3600 + 300), key_id, 121],
        [t_0 + timedelta(seconds=3600 + 360), key_id, 1],
        [t_0 + timedelta(seconds=7200 + 1800), key_id, 2],
    ]
    df = pandas.DataFrame(list(map(lambda r: list(r), data)), columns=["TS", "KeyId", "Value"])
    df_pivot = (df
           .pivot(index="TS", columns="KeyId", values="Value")
           .ffill()
           .rename({key_id: key_label}, axis='columns')
        )

    def mymean(*args, **kwargs):
        expected_results = [numpy.NaN, 0.5, 3, 1.5]
        d0 = args[0].index[0]
        if d0 == data[0][0]:
            return expected_results[0]
        if d0 == data[1][0]:
            return expected_results[1]
        if d0 == data[2][0]:
            return expected_results[2]
        if d0 == data[4][0]:
            return expected_results[3]
        return "???"

    results = (df_pivot
           .resample('1H')
           .agg(["min", "max", "mean", "count", mymean])
          )

    display(df_pivot)
    display(results)
```

Expected result is in column `mymean`. There are two values between 13:00 and 14:00. Average of those two values is 61, but the sensor stays at 121 just for a minute, so the expected average should be 3 (for the lazy reader: (1*59 + 121*1) / 60).

```
KeyId   Sensor1
TS  
2010-01-02 11:58:00     0
2010-01-02 12:30:00     1
2010-01-02 13:05:00     121
2010-01-02 13:06:00     1
2010-01-02 14:30:00     2

    Sensor1
    min     max     mean    count   mymean
TS                  
2010-01-02 11:00:00     0   0   0   1   NaN
2010-01-02 12:00:00     1   1   1   1   0.5
2010-01-02 13:00:00     1   121 61  2   3.0
2010-01-02 14:00:00     2   2   2   1   1.5
```

I could upsample to the sampling frequency, `ffill` and average, but that looks very inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this:

1. Add rows marking the beginning of each group, give them values with `ffill`:

```py
extra_times = pandas.date_range(t_0, periods=3, freq='1H')
pdf_reindexed = (pandas
    .concat([pdf_query, pandas.DataFrame(index=extra_times)], sort=False)
    .sort_index()
    .ffill()
    )
```

2. Add a difference column `span`:

```py
timestamp = pdf_reindexed.index.to_series()
pdf_reindexed["span"] = (timestamp.shift(-1) - timestamp).dt.seconds
```

3. Multiply `value` by `span`:

```py
pdf_reindexed["product"] = pdf_reindexed["span"] * pdf_reindexed["Sensor1"]
```

4. Aggregate and divide:

```py
pdf_time_mean = (pdf_reindexed
                 .resample("1H")
                 .agg({"product": "sum"})
                )
pdf_time_mean["product"] = pdf_time_mean["product"] / 3600
```